# Joomla Search Engine in other language than English

Tags: joomla, search-engine

I would like to change the language of the standard search engine from Joomla, from English to Dutch. How do I do that? Or is it only available in English and do I need to search for a new engine that supports Dutch? 'Cause I can't find one of those... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything. Joomla (and any other CMS) searches for given keywords "as is". Language doesn't matter, if your database encoding (collation) is properly set. And if you didn't change anything manually, everything is good.

So just search and have fun!